Clickhouse cascading materialized view not updating despite source table/materialized view is successfully having data inserted
I have created a cascading materialized view in Clickhouse, however the 2nd materialized view does not receive any data. This is despite data being populated in the first materialized view table from which the 2nd materialized view reads inserted data blocks from.
From reading the docs, since ClickHouse materialized views work by reading the insert blocks, if data is present in the first materialized view then there is no reason it should not be processed and inserted in the second view. However, no rows are ever present in the station_stats_minute table despite no other errors.
Would anybody be able to identify why this is happening for the following table/view schemas ?
For referencem I have been following this article from the ClickHouse blog in creating the tables and views.
The schema of each table is as follows:
Table 1 - Data Entry Table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  tracking.logs (
    created_at DateTime DEFAULT now(),
    message String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(created_at)
ORDER BY (created_at)
TTL created_at + INTERVAL 15 DAY;

Table 2 - Data parse table/mat view
CREATE TABLE .tracking_events
(
    event_datetime DateTime,
    message_id String,
    user_id String,
    station_id String,
    message_type String
)
    ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY event_datetime;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tracking.tracking_events_mv
TO tracking.tracking_events
AS
SELECT
    parseDateTimeBestEffort(JSONExtractString(message, 'timestamp')) AS event_datetime,
    JSONExtractString(message, 'fields', 'message_id') AS message_id,
    JSONExtractString(message, 'fields', 'user_id') AS user_id,
    JSONExtractString(message, 'fields', 'station_id') AS station_id,
    JSONExtractString(message, 'fields', 'message_type') AS message_type
FROM tracking.logs
WHERE JSONExtractString(message, 'fields', 'message') = 'new message'

Table 3 - Data Aggregation table/mat view
CREATE TABLE tracking.station_stats_minute
(
    `minute` DateTime,
    `station_id` String,
    `message_count` UInt32
)
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(`minute`)
ORDER BY (`minute`, station_id)
TTL `minute` + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tracking.station_stats_minute_mv
to tracking.station_stats_minute
AS
SELECT
    toStartOfMinute(event_datetime) AS `minute`,
    `station_id`,
    count() AS `message_count`
FROM tracking.tracking_events
GROUP BY
    `minute`,
    station_id;


I am expecting aggregated data to be populated in the table tracking.station_stats_minute and that data to be sourced from the tracking_events materialized view table tracking_events.

try turn on system.query_views_log and figure out what exactly happens
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/query_views_log

try to remove TTL minute + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

The TLL statement was the issue. Could you post this as a answer so I can accept it ?

ClickHouse MV only process data when new data is inserted into the source table. Cascading MV require the second view to reference the destination table (storage table) created by the first MV. Double-check that your second MV is correctly referencing this table in its FROM clause.
So, based on the info, the second MV (tracking.station_stats_minute_mv) is supposed to receive data from the first MV's destination table (tracking.tracking_events). However, if the first MV (tracking.tracking_events_mv) isn't set up to properly trigger inserts into tracking.tracking_events, the second view will not receive any data.
MV only forward the data blocks that are inserted, not the final processed data. Therefore, if the second view is not triggering correctly, it could be because no new data is being inserted into tracking.tracking_events after the first view processes the data.
Try inserting new data into the tracking.logs table and see if it triggers the updates in the second MV.

In this fiddle (https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/bd8a3936-621d-46ec-b539-8df7ed726692) another user was able to verify that it should populate data in the materialized view when data is inserted into logs. By manually adding data with a time stamp in the future I was able to have data generated for the minute aggregated view in my own clickhouse instance.
Looks like the TTL is the likely culprit for why data is not forwarded.
